# Error-AttributeError: module 'pyodbc' has no attribute 'Connect'

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

Anyone have the suggestion to fix it.
Using the below code to extract the 2 columns values from the Db

but getting the below error.
Error-AttributeError: module 'pyodbc' has no attribute 'Connect'

Code--
import pyodbc
cnxn =pyodbc.Connect(

Comment: try with lowercase `pyodbc.connect`